# LibGDX mouse position in world deviation

Tags: java, libgdx, mouse-position

I ve got some problem with mouse position in game world in LibGDX.
There is some difference between my mouse position in world and real position.
To get my mouse position Im using:

```
Vector3 mousePos = gamecam.unproject(new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
speechBaloon.setPosition(mousePos.x, mousePos.y); //texture that follows cursor
```

where:

```
public static final int WIDTH = 1920;
public static final int HEIGHT = 1080;


gamecam = new OrthographicCamera();
gamePort = new FitViewport(MyGame.WIDTH, MyGame.HEIGHT, gamecam);
gamecam.setToOrtho(false, MyGame.WIDTH, MyGame.HEIGHT);
```

Here some photos(added mouse coursor by myself, cuz my screens program doesnt have options to capture photo with cursor, but scale between distance is preserved):

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDBou.jpg)

[img2 - full resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYPkm.jpg)

As u can see in *img2* there is a difference between X position, and in *img1* between Y. I cannot post more than 2 photos, but when I drag cursor to the center of Y axis in situation from *img1*, my texture and cursor are covering themselves.

I have resize function (my class implements Screen).

```
@Override
    public void resize(int width, int height)
    {
        gamePort.update(width, height);
        hudPort.update(width, height);
    }
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Since you're using a Viewport, you need to unprojected using the viewport instead of the camera so it will take the black bars into account.

Answer (score 1):

Like [Tenfour04](https://stackoverflow.com/users/506796/tenfour04) noticed as long as [Viewport](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/viewport/Viewport.html) (`gamePort`) is used we need to call [.unproject()](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/viewport/Viewport.html#unproject-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-) on Viewport instance.

From documentation of LibGDX [Camera](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.html#unproject-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-):

> Function to translate a point given in screen coordinates to world
>   space. ...
>   The viewport is assumed to span the whole screen and is fetched from
>   [Graphics.getWidth()](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Graphics.html#getWidth--) and [Graphics.getHeight()](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Graphics.html#getHeight--).

---

Final outcome:

```
Vector3 mousePos = gamePort.unproject(new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
speechBaloon.setPosition(mousePos.x, mousePos.y); //texture that follows cursor
```